# HTML HELP WORKSHOP - Adding to TOC

Tags: html-help-workshop

I have a help project consisting of a number of files in the \html subdirectory of the directory where the .hlp project file resides.  I added a new file called x.htm under the project tab and populated it with some html code; the file ended up in the \html directory.  I next went to the Contents tab and added a topic file.  If I double click the file/topic from under the Project or Contents, the file is displayed.  BUT when I compile the project, I get the error "Error: URL reference in the TOC cannot be resolved".  I suspect HTML Workshop is trying to open project\x.htm rather than project\html\x.htm because if I click on the Edit Selection on the Contents tab x is displayed as x.htm whereas other contents entries are displayed as html\other.htm.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I had to add the html\ to the front of the file displayed in the 'Path or URL' dialog box displayed in response to the 'Add' or 'Edit' button in the 'Table of Contents dialog box  displayed in response to the Edit Selection button under the contents tab in the main window.  Is it just me or do others find this app confusing? :-(